# How to use the html binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I encounter a problem when using the `html` binding in knockoutjs. In the `viewModel.maintable()` I have:

```
this.layerDetails = ko.observable("");
```

In a function that I add some html in the above attribute:

```
viewModel.maintable().layerDetails(viewModel.maintable().layerDetails() + "<a href='#' data-bind='click:function(){viewModel.refreshPage(true)}'>link</a>");
```

Also in html part:

```html
<div data-bind='html: layerDetails'>a</div>
```

However, I can't trigger the `refreshPage` function. Did I write the wrong code?

Comment: shouldn't it be `viewModel.layerDetails("your new html")` ?

Comment: TO nEEbz: actually I want to add one link in the <div> in a loop to make a paging effect, therefore I add the new string of html to the attribute for each page rather than replacing the attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `html` binding will not hook up any data-bind attributes.  You really have a couple of choices to make this work.

1- use the `template` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) instead of html.  Create a template with your content and Knockout will manage adding/removing DOM elements and hooking up the data-binds.

2- call `ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel, theNewRootElement)` after setting the layerDetails value.  So, you would pass in the data that you want bound and the root of any new elements that were created.

Comment: To RP Niemeyer: thanks for your help! As I want to add html into the attribute for each item using a looping that I didn't use first method . I applied the second method and it can trigger the function now.